# Using CDI in a websphere shared library

Tags: java, dependency-injection, shared-libraries, cdi, websphere-8

We use a shared library defined in the websphere admin console to share classes between several applications. I was wondering if it is possible to use CDI (Context and Dependecy Injection) in these classes? If so do I just need to put the beans.xml in the jar that is in the shared library, or are there further steps?

Note: I can't move away from using a shared library, as this would be too much refactoring work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, classes included in a shared library are not considered as CDI beans.  Only archives included in the application itself can be considered for CDI.